# UISearch Controller Showing data not part of the filtered array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My Question is this. Why is the filtered table view showing rooms, after I start typing in the search bar  that are not present when printing the filtered array to the console. I thought it might be that the table view cells are being reused so set the cell label text to nil to ensure the text gets reset in tableviewcellforindex: method , all to no avail. Can anyone help?

This is my Table View Controller that acts as the data source and delegate for for both my standard tableview and filtered tableview

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Rooms.h"

@interface RoomsTableViewController : UITableViewController
<UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *roomList;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *orderedRoomList;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredRooms;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UITableViewController *searchResultsController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;

@end


#import "RoomsTableViewController.h"

@interface RoomsTableViewController ()
@property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
@property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;

@end
```

The implementation file

```
@implementation RoomsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//sort the room list into filetred by alpha numeric A10 before C1 example this will eventually be done on the server

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
    self.orderedRoomList = (NSMutableArray*)[self.roomList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


    self.searchResultsController= [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater=self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=self.searchController.searchBar;

    //set up the data source and delegate of this new table view to be this (roomsTableviewcontroller) view controller
    self.searchResultsController.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.searchController.delegate=self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation=NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate=self;

    self.definesPresentationContext=YES;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //restore the search controllers active state
    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive=NO;
        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder=NO;

        }

    }
}

-(void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}




#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView==self.tableView) {
        return [self.orderedRoomList count];
    }else{
        return [self.filteredRooms count];
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 71;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellReuseIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    }

Rooms *room = (tableView==self.tableView)? [self.orderedRoomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]: [self.filteredRooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=nil;

    NSString *labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",room.name,room.roomDescription];
    cell.textLabel.text=labelString;

    return cell;

}
```

Below is a photo of the table view in the simulator and a screen print of the check to see if the filtered array has indeed worked correctly as it has. You can see that C3 is not listed as being part of the filtered array but it still appears on screen.

[image]

Comment: what is this TableViewController for `@property (strong,nonatomic) UITableViewController *searchResultsController;`?

Comment: the `UISearchController` has its own table view controller to display the filtered results.

Comment: self.orderedRoomList = (NSMutableArray*)[self.roomList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
correct is:
  self.orderedRoomList = [[self.roomList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]] mutableCopy];

Comment: The tableviewcontroller roomstableview controller in this instance is both:  self.searchResultsController.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource=self;